# DBeaver (or similar): is there a way to disactivate a row temporarily?

Tags: sql, database, dbeaver

I have an application that accesses data from an SQL database and would like to make a test what would happen if some of the rows weren't present. I'm visualizing the data using DBeaver and it would be great if I could mark some lines to 'deactivate', i.e. delete them from the DB but still keep them as new lines locally, which I can readd later on. 
 
Is DBeaver able to do that? Is there another tool which can?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply EXPORT your data from the table, and import them again when you finish your test.

from what I know there is no way to hide rows.
if you want to export data from your table:

> RIGHT CLICK ON THE SELECTED TABLE

> EXPORT

> CHOOSE YOUR PREFERRED EXPORT FORMAT

You could also make a backup of the table in its current state, and when you have finished your work you can do a rollback.

BACKUP:

> RIGHT CLICK ON THE SELECTED TABLE

> INTRUMENT

> BACKUP